# opendaylight flow is pushed but does not appear in flow list

Tags: curl, opendaylight

I am trying to push flow in opendaylight via curl in xml format. It successfully pushes and I am able to see it under http://localnetwork:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory:nodes but can not see it via command of ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1, flow does not work as well.

I can push flows and see in flow table within ovs ==> ovs-ofctl add-flow and curl in json format as well. Both mininet and odl runs with openflow13. Any idea?

command I use:

curl --user "admin":"admin" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-type: application/xml" -X PUT -d @Flow1DisablePing.xml http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory:nodes
/node/openflow:1/table/0/flow/1

Comment: what is the flow or action your adding and also have you captured packet

Comment: hello Karthik, I belive I found out the problem. I checked openvswitch logs and saw a line rejecting my flow due to wildcard mask. I changed my flows  match criteria from ip to mac and it worked like a charm. The weird thing is flow actually in both operational and config datastore, so I didnt check ovs switch logs. now I better solve this error: 2017-01-07T08:29:24.751Z|101052|nx_match|WARN|Rejecting NXM/OXM entry 0:32768:12:1:8 with 1-bits in value for bits wildcarded by the mask.

Comment: edit:2 I changed ip addresses from 10.0.0.1/8 to 10.0.0.1/32, they worked too. Do not know if it is bug or my fault.